# IE: Problem with local content and Flash

Tags: javascript, flash, internet-explorer

I am using `TGetProperty` in Javascript to interact with a Flash movie. This works fine in IE when hosted from a web server, but if I try and open the page from a local drive, the Javascript loses the ability to communicate with the Flash movie and returns an 'Unspecified error'.

I presume this is happening due to a restrictive security policy regarding local content.

What can I do to overcome this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)

Answer (score 1):

will not work

you need to change the security defenitions at this link:
http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html

zach